# How to GetFileReference to an Azure blob/file if I have the _full_ absolute uri?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

In my database I have the full absolute `Uri` to our azure files.

eg.

- `https://<snip>.file.core.windows.net/share1/Brand1/Export_2017-05-11-12-54.xml`
- `https://<snip>.file.core.windows.net/share1/Brand1/asdfasdfasd.xml`
- `https://<snip>.file.core.windows.net/share1/Brand2/PewPew%20-%20Sample-78206580-1dd8-4de2-9b92-002bdca861a5.xml`

Please note:

- Azure files `Share` name e.g. `share1`
- The file names have one ore more `/` in em. e.g. `brand1/blah.xml`

I'm trying to see if the file exists and then do stuff with it (e.g. download it, whatever).

I need to get a `File Reference` to this item first. I've done all the ceremony to set *that* up (`SAS`, etc).

This is how I get a file reference to a file:

`var cloudFile = ShareRootDirectory.GetFileReference(fileName);`

if the `fileName = "Brand1/Export_2017-05-11-12-54.xml` it would work (note: no `share` or `https://....` there.)

otherwise I get an error.

**Is there some way, given a full absolute uri to a file on azure, can I pass *something* to my previously setup `ShreRootDirectory` to get/check the file? Or do I need to do it another way?**

Is there some trick?

Note: 
- I have a share folder (for files)
- Filenames have `/` in them which gives the illusion of folders.

Here's a screen shot of me doing this:

`var tempCloudFile = new CloudFile(new Uri(fileName));`

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to storage credentials or just the File URI?

Comment: I do - somewhere :) Eg. `StorageAccount.Credentials` ?

Comment: Can you share your script? I have a same requirement where I need to look for file "Text.CSV" in Azure Blob container and I am not sure how to define a file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to storage credentials, you can use the following override of [`CloudFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_File_CloudFile__ctor_System_Uri_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Auth_StorageCredentials_) to get a reference for that file and then perform operations on that file. For example, I get a reference for CloudFile below and checking for its existence.

```
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var file = new CloudFile(new Uri("https://<snip>.file.core.windows.net/share1/Brand1/Export_2017-05-11-12-54.xml"), cred);
        var exists = file.Exists();
```

Comment: AH! hahaha! purrrrrfect!

Comment: another words if we have a URL like this: `https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/input/DisabledFlights[1].cache` then it is impossible to get a reference without credentials?